# cmake for OpenCV doesn't detect jdk

Tags: java, opencv, cmake

I want to to compile OpenCV 2.4.10 with Java native interface. I use this guide [Introduction to Java Development](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html).
It says that I should have installed JDK. I installed it by using this command: `yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel` and set `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75`

Now I try to run `cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..`

Its output 'OpenCV modules' section is:

```
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 core flann imgproc highgui features2d calib3d ml video legacy objdetect photo gpu ocl nonfree contrib stitching superres ts videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 androidcamera dynamicuda java python viz
```

As you see cmake consider java unavailable.
What should I do for make OpenCV with java support?

Comment: check the JAVA_HOME value. Normally, your installed java lib should be /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-something/, not the one you cite in your question.

Comment: @HaDang I have 3 folderse there:    `jre-1.7.0/                                       jre-1.7.0-openjdk/                               jre-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/
`

Comment: oh yeah? Now look at the command export JAVA_HOME that you give in your question. Does the folder /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_75 exist?

Comment: @HaDang I changed it to jre-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.75-2.5.4.2.el7_0.x86_64/ but cmake doesn't detect jdk again.

Comment: Look closely to the folder path, it should be /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-something, not /usr/java/jre-1.7.0-something

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it. Cmake for opencv needs ANT, but I didn't have it. For now cmake can make opencv with java support.

Comment: Would you mind to accept your answer? Then it is clear, that your question is no longer open.